# powershell invoke-expression java program get status

Tags: java, powershell, status

I'm running a jar from powershell using `Invoke-Expression`:

```
$line="c:\temp\my file.txt"
$cmd="java -jar C:\temp\post.jar `"" +  $line + "`""
invoke-expression $cmd
```

If I test `$?` it will only give me the status of `Invoke-Expression` which will always be a success as the java executable and post.jar can be found.

Also, I've thought of running the java program directly and test `$?` but sometimes the file name can be very complex and sometimes I put extra options.

How do I get the status of the run of the post.jar program?

Thanks.

Comment: Do not use `Invoke-Expression`. It is unnecessary in this case.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to check the exit code of the process via:

```
$p = Start-Process java -ArgumentList '-jar C:\temp\post.jar',$file -Wait -PassThru
$p.ExitCode
```

Based on `-PassThru` you'll receive a `System.Diagnostics.Process`-object that should include the exit-code of the jar. For more info see the [Start-Process cmdlet description](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Management/Start-Process?view=powershell-5.1).

Hope that helps.